# FFmpeg: Can I replace libx264 with OpenH264 in order to go LGPL?

Tags: licensing, gpl, lgpl

I have some video processing to run and FFmpeg already contains much of what I need. However my videos are all compressed with H.264 video codec and [libx264](http://x264licensing.com/faq) is a GPL part of FFmpeg. On the other hand, the Constrained Baseline Profile is pretty enough for my application which means I could perfectly use [OpenH264](http://www.openh264.org/). So would it be possible both in theory and in practice to make this replacement?

Comment: I believe that using a GPL-licensed program to process your videos does not mean the videos themselves must be provided to viewers under specific licensing terms. So the question disappears.

Comment: Hi Alex, I believe you're saying in the strict sense of decode-only. Eventually I will need to re-encode videos because the processing consists on separating a big video into several pieces. So in that case I will need OpenH264 to stay away from royalties, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As OpenH264 is available under a permissive, BSD-style license, it it legally possible to create a version of it that will work as a codec for FFmpeg.
Given enough time, I am sure that it is also technically possible to create a FFmpeg compatible version of OpenH264.

The remaining question is if it makes economic/business sense to create a wrapper around OpenH264 or to modify OpenH264 itself to fit the expected codec API of FFmpeg. This question can only be answered by yourself.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought and that answers my question as I got an opinion from someone more experienced. For the moment, OpenH264 is simply not mature enough and many hours would be needed to include it to a project.